# LINQ to XML Cloning

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xelement

Can anyone explain why the original address XElement street node changes? It looks like customer1 holds a reference to the address XElement but customer2 and customer3 have taken copies.

Why did the original address change? (LINQPad example)

```
var address =
    new XElement ("address",
        new XElement ("street", "Lawley St"), 
        new XElement ("town", "North Beach")
    );

var customer1 = new XElement ("customer1", address);
var customer2 = new XElement ("customer2", address);
var customer3 = new XElement ("customer3", address);

customer1.Element ("address").Element ("street").Value = "Another St";

Console.WriteLine (customer2.Element ("address").Element ("street").Value);
Console.WriteLine ();

address.Dump();
Console.WriteLine ();

customer1.Dump();
Console.WriteLine ();

customer2.Dump();
Console.WriteLine ();

customer3.Dump();
```

## OUTPUT

```
Lawley St


<address>
  <street>Another St</street>
  <town>North Beach</town>
</address> 


<customer1>
  <address>
    <street>Another St</street>
    <town>North Beach</town>
  </address>
</customer1> 


<customer2>
  <address>
    <street>Lawley St</street>
    <town>North Beach</town>
  </address>
</customer2> 


<customer3>
  <address>
    <street>Lawley St</street>
    <town>North Beach</town>
  </address>
</customer3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same XElement cannot be in multiple trees.  You can certainly have multiple references to the same XElement in a particular tree, but **the same XElement cannot be in multiple trees**.

To `customer1`, you really and truly added that `address` XElement.  By the time you "added" it to `customer2`, the actual `address1` XElement could not really be added, because it's already a node in another XElement.  Since it could not add the original `address` as a node, the XElement constructor places a clone of that XElement in `customer2` and `customer3`.  You now have three equivalent "address" XElements.

Answer (score 8):

From the question:

> It looks like customer1 holds a
>   reference to the address XElement but
>   customer2 and customer3 have taken
>   copies.

Yes, that's exactly what happens. From the [docs for XElement contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882(v=VS.100).aspx):

> When adding XNode or XAttribute
>   objects, if the new content has no
>   parent, then the objects are simply
>   attached to the XML tree. If the new
>   content already is parented and is
>   part of another XML tree, then the new
>   content is cloned, and the newly
>   cloned content is attached to the XML
>   tree.

In the first case, `address` has no parent so it's attached directly. Afterwards, it *does* have a parent, so it's cloned first.